# How to delete rows containing 75% missing values and what impute technique to use?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a dataframe 17631x15 and would like to find an easy way to remove rows that contain 75% missing values. I am not sure how to fill in the threshold in a function:

```
out<- rowSums(is.na(df))
```

My data is showing strong diurnal and seasonal variability and I am wondering if the missing values can be replaced with the geometric mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as removing the rows, you can do:

```
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1), 1500, replace = T), ncol = 15))
df_sub <- df[rowSums(is.na(df))/ncol(df) <0.75, ]
```

As far as imputing missing values, the main package is `mice`. In this package there are multiple imputations based on a variety of techniques depending on your data type. In addition, you can use `missForest` package for mixed data as well. Check those to start with.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!